# How the dlls in an ASP.NET bin folder get updated?

Tags: asp.net, dll, build, bin

We have some DLLs in the `bin` folder. We build the DLLs in separate solutions and output to different directories. Now, when I build the web site, the DLLs in its `bin` folder gets updated automatically with the latest version (from those dirs). Now I am wondering how does that work? I mean, how did the build know from where to pull the latest bits of my DLLs? That looks magic to me...

Answer (score 0):

When building the web site, you must be referencing the DLLs from the other folder.

Comment: sorry @sachin, what did u mean the 'other folder'?

Comment: oops .. i meant the directory where the dlls are output to.

Answer (score 0):

When the website is getting build, the dlls will be copied to the target directory from the referenced location. Please check if the CopyLocal is set to True or False for each reference.

Comment: for the website, it doesn't have a project file. so I see no where the references are declared (as a normal c# project would have). the only reference are the dll themselves in the website's bin folder. but magically (to me), the dlls will be auto-refreshed when I build the web site.